# vsprintf function not working with structure 2d array

Tags: c, printf

I am creating some wrapper functions using vsprintf() function but its failing if column value > 0 .I compiled this code with different complier but getting the same result. You can check result of this code here -> [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMJATlIOAMngMmABy7gBGmMQSAKykAA6oCoS2DM5uHt7xickCAUGhLBFRXLGWmNYpQgRMxARp7p5cPmUVAlU1BHkh4ZExFtW19RlN/R1dBUUxAJQWqK7EyOwcAKQaAILLAEwAzIHIblgA1MvbjgoE%2BKgAdAgn2KsbO3sHmMen58SBwDd3D1u7DH2riOJzOFxq31u23u6z%2BOywNCChwAsmsABrGABKAHkAOqHSRw7YIwKvVEYxzYvyHLgANj%2B6wIAE84pgEYcPq5rMcAOwAIQehyFh1cDBSvIF62F0plyAQNUO6CY1WW0T55KxeNVABFVer0cZKX4dSdJWsZRbDnKFWEmQRMAo9RqcfiAFQog1Gk3bM2W3m6n2CoXW4gcvAAL0wpr%2BPO1yOMfLkADEk9hMcYACostmYKjR2HrEMohOuKhUSLKT6CKgQeOJlNpzPZ9musKl8tkNAMc5W%2BWh11UFgEUhF4ioADuI77VpcpCu86mEqDQuXhzwNbH47e2A9GJdU1XQuImAI8wYhw0%2BY2UuFADcmMZaHgexCr6v78Zzh0IBCRy4D4GN4rkBhy3gocRVgQNYQEWroHpstJtmWkQALR3EqKpqpuJpqmgtA6nwQ6kBCAG%2BsK74Pg4P7EMApEMuawrHqexDnlwb6xvRgQEIcLBMIEECLss/LLsudbJqm6ZZqy7JIR2bzakuIHCpeQFCQGZHHEBdbthWkE1lsiE6WQWybAAEocIDHJs0ToFZ0RXBomx5psmykBobmkLEXBXAhXjRHRWklshxCVlx%2BkIbJkSkCZ5mWVsNl2Q5TkmaQXCkK5tKkNsGg%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%2BVAMnSkhM6%2BjDv6Rj1%2BtSr5MXAzAomOLHoceYEsPAw3DPMO6jHCqGTtIUK0kkIcYAyBkA0m8psQ4EBHCkEOLgQgJArLbDSocZwyt6ChhxlMXgIstBTGJiAbKPkeTM0kOTMm1kNDRB5K5Tm3NSCI2Rr/AWQs8YExmBLRAIA5gEDiAHcglBpayywXoNkSCZ4F2EKIcQpdpEVzULHY879eDjkjnEROn8ODwyYbzX%2B2IA4CO4qgKghx/6AOAaA8BkCfIwIwaIyIKD754M4UQzY3k6QuS8C5HkGgyZcFZhQ/QnBGHMN4Kwiw7D8GExCRwTY38WH8w4aLQhpAvZ6xSKTIAA%3D)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define MAX_ROW 4
#define MAX_COL 16

typedef struct {
union {
        char data[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
        char bytes[MAX_ROW * MAX_COL];
    };
 char size;
}M_BUFFER_Typedef;

char M_BufferPrintf(M_BUFFER_Typedef *buffer,const char *fmt,char row,char col,...) {

  if(row > MAX_ROW)
   return 0;

   va_list arg;

   va_start(arg,col);

   vsprintf((char *)&buffer->data[row][col],fmt,arg);

   va_end(arg);

   return 1;
}

int main() {

  M_BUFFER_Typedef buffer = {
     0
  };

  M_BufferPrintf(&buffer,"H : %d %.02f",0,0,5,1.2695);
  M_BufferPrintf(&buffer,"H : %d %.02f",1,2,6,30.2695);
  M_BufferPrintf(&buffer,"H %.02f",2,0,100.2695);
  M_BufferPrintf(&buffer,"H : %d ",3,0,9);

  printf("\n%s",buffer.data[0]);
  printf("\n%s",buffer.data[1]);
  printf("\n%s",buffer.data[2]);
  printf("\n%s",buffer.data[3]);
}
```

Code output:

```
> ASM generation compiler returned: 0
> Execution build compiler returned: 0\n
> Program returned: 0

H : 5 1.27
//if col value 2 -> nothing copied here 
H 100.27 
H : 9
```

Comment: please check now,below the code

Comment: Printf not printing anything because first 2 characters are null in buffer.data[1][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, nothing is failing - you simply do not understand how it works

The second one does not work as you expect because you print from the first character of row `1` , but `vsprintf` has written starting from the char number three and the two first characters are still zero.

if you change the line printing it to:

```
  printf("\n%s",&buffer.data[1][2]);
```

It will print what you expect there.

You can print the content of the row to see what is there:

```
  printf("Content of the row 2: "); for(int i =0; i < MAX_COL; i++) printf("%d ", buffer.data[1][i]);
  printf("\n");
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nav4EK6WT

As you see the row starts from the null character, thus printf the string outputs nothing.